# How do I set any data while script still executing?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, apache

Right now I'm using an event-stream to echo the upload progress from another script to the user, but no matter how I try to pass the variable from the form-data progressing php file to my event-stream file, it doesn't work.

The problem is, that all changes I make in my running php script for the file upload **only become visible after full script execution** on my server, while it's working fine on my local machine.

I've tried writing to files in my web directory, in the tmp directory and using a mysql database, but none of them worked.

Here's what my upload progressing php script roughly looks like with the sql solution:

```
$progress = 0;
foreach ($files as $file) {
    sql("UPDATE `tmp` SET `progress`=? WHERE `ID`=?", $progress, $id);
    imagejpeg($image, "images/gallery/$filename.jpg", 100);
    $progress++;
}
```

And my event-stream php script:

```
echo "data: ".sql("SELECT `progress` FROM `tmp` WHERE `ID`=?", $id)."\n\n";
```

I would appreciate any solution how to solve this problem, best without installing any php libraries.

Thanks

Comment: you realize that "xampp" is using apache internally? That's what the `a` is... you need to specify which VERSIONS of apache and php you're using on both machines.

Comment: @MarcB I'm using php/5.3 apache/2.2.22 (linux) on my web server and php/5.5 apache/2.4.10 (windows) on my PC. I'm not sure why exactly the changes I make in my php script only apply after finishing or whether it is caused by any system differences.

Comment: could be something as simple as using file-based sessions, meaning your progress script cannot execute until the upload completes, because the upload script is locking the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem by flushing the progress to the user over the upload script and handling the output by checking the xhr.responseText periodically.

PHP (flushes line break + progress)

```
foreach ($files as $drop => $file) {
    echo "\n$progress";
    flush();
    // file progressing
}
```

JavaScript (gets progress after last line break)

```
setInterval(function() {
    if (page.xhr.readyState == 3 && page.xhr.status == 200) {
        var response = page.xhr.responseText;
        $('#progress').stop().animate({width: parseFloat(response.substr(response.lastIndexOf("\n")+1))+'%'}, 480);
    }   
}, 1000);
```